# Como recorrer un array de html con JQuery o javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
<td>
    <input type="text" name="listPeso[]" class="input_next autoNumeric" data-v-min="0.000" data-v-max="999999999999999999999.999" data-a-sep="" data-a-dec="."  onkeyup="runScript(event,this)">
</td>
```

La cual se van incrementado según lo necesite el usuario, así que tendría `N` etiquetas con el nombre de `listPeso[]`, los cuales debo de sumar para mostrar el peso total.

**El problema es:**

> No se como recorrerlos con javascript o con JQuery.

Intente algo como:

```
var dom=document.getElementsByName("listPeso[]");
console.log(dom);
```

Para obtener los datos, pero están vacíos, ademas intente con:

```
$("input[name='listPeso[]']").each(function(indice, elemento) {
    console.log('El elemento con el índice '+indice+' contiene '+$(elemento).text());
});
```

Pero no consigo resultados.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Debes tener en cuenta que para capturar el valor de un `input` se utiliza el método `.val()` y no `.text()`.

Retiré los `onkeyup` en el ejemplo para que no generara errores al momento de ejecutar el snippet.

```js
$("#ejecutar").click(function(){
  $("input[name='listPeso[]']").each(function(indice, elemento) {
    console.log('El elemento con el índice '+indice+' contiene '+$(elemento).val());
});
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<td>
    <input type="text" name="listPeso[]" class="input_next autoNumeric" data-v-min="0.000" data-v-max="999999999999999999999.999" data-a-sep="" data-a-dec=".">
</td>

<td>
    <input type="text" name="listPeso[]" class="input_next autoNumeric" data-v-min="0.000" data-v-max="999999999999999999999.999" data-a-sep="" data-a-dec=".">
</td>

<td>
    <input type="text" name="listPeso[]" class="input_next autoNumeric" data-v-min="0.000" data-v-max="999999999999999999999.999" data-a-sep="" data-a-dec=".">
</td>

<button id="ejecutar">Ejecutar</button>
```

Comment: Hola master @Bender ayudame con una pregunta relacionada con tu respuesta, que sucede si no le pongo los `[]` al input en este caso `name="listPeso[]"`, podria recorrelo de igual forma ?

Comment: @srJJ si quitas los corchetes de los name de cada input debes quitarlos también en el selector de jQuery para que los pueda reconocer y recorrer

Comment: mmmm. ya, pero de igual forma podria recorrelo los inputs con el mismo name, pensaba que lo que hacia el poder recorrelos eran los corchetes...

Comment: @srJJ no necesariamente, el detecta los name y los recorre independiente de si tienen corchetes o no, sería lo mismo que si eligiera recorrerlos usando las clases de ellos, saludos.

Comment: muchas gracias por la explicacion bro, exitos !

Comment: @srJJ siempre que necesites ayuda me encontrarás en el [chat], saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias, esta genial tu solución